# Shell .Net4.5 Metro Design Application

Tags: shell, microsoft-metro

I want to run another .exe file in my Metro Design Application. There is `shell` in .Net 4.5 but I understand that it works only in WPF applications and not in Metro Design apps. How can I run another process in my metro design application?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are doing ? You are developing in and for Windows 8, right !? Are you developing for desktop or a metro app ? you want to launch another app from your app ? is that it ?

Comment: Exactly I have a windows 8 metro design application and inside it I want to run another .exe file. I am developing a metro design application! (The program ı want to run is written in .net4 Also might it cause a problem?)

Comment: My question has changed! Sorry for inconveniance first of all.

Comment: I m writing a code a Metro Design Application(NOT WPF!)(Program1). I have another executable program which is written in .NET4(Program2.exe). I want to call Program2 from my application(Program1) and get the results of Program2 to my application(Program1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Metro style apps build against a version of the .NET Framework that is a little different to the traditional .NET Framework" at this 
[Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/745b6421-1a30-4ea3-a730-bb05d3e22650) that talks about porting .net to Metro apps. 
Also check [.NET for Metro style apps overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Regarding your other question there is no API in metro like SellExecute or createprocess so you cannot launch other programs as is.
You can however use protocol Handlers. A metro app can register a protocol handler, or use existing handlers. Think of http:// or mail:// that launches the default app registered for that handler. You can use custom handler if they are not yet registered ...